# Get total amount of items in for loop

Tags: python, html, django

```
<div class="imageCounter">
     {% for item in page.blogpage_images.all %}
     {{ forloop.counter }} of {{ forloop.counter }}
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

`of {{ forloop.counter }}` is the part that I would like to display the number of items in the list if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just display a count of the blog page images:

```
{% for item in page.blogpage_images.all %}
    {{ forloop.counter }} of {{ page.blogpage_images.all.count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Amazing thank you! I've tried so many different ways using `forloop` and `item`